# Proving：for all $p>0$, $A_n=\sum_1^\infty \sin({n^p})$ is divergent

Tags: calculus, analysis

I have proven that $A_n$ is divergent for $-1 < p<0$, and convergent for $p<-1$.

Comment: I have proven that $A_n$ is convergent for p<-1,and divergent for -1<p<0

Comment: The right side doesn't have any $n$ in it.

Comment: sorry,it is $\sin{n^p}$

Comment: Then what is the index for the sum, is both $p,n$ fixed? And is it $\sin(n^p)$ or $\sin(n)^p$?

Comment: p is fixed,$\sin{(n^p)}$

Comment: @syg Then the sum is over $n$? As in $$A_n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n^p)$$? If so, then it doesn't make sense to talk about "$A_n$", because $n$ is not fixed either.

Comment: When you figure out what you actually mean, sy, please edit the title and body of your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you're asking, so I will assume that you're interested in the bevhaviour of $$A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin(n^p)$$

$A$ diverges for $p\geq 0$, since $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sin(n^p)$$ doesn't exist. To see this choose $n=\sqrt[p]{\frac{N\pi}{2}}$ which gets arbitrarily big with increasing $N$, and then $\sin(n^p)=1$, but with $n'=\sqrt[p]{2}n$ you get $\sin((n')^p)=0$.

Also, are you sure that $A$ diverges for $p<-1$?

Comment: "It is not clear what you're asking..." so maybe we should wait until OP figures out what the question really is?